# Application.properties validator

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, properties-file

I want to make some kind of properties validation in my spring boot aplication. In my application.properties I have something like this:

```
log.path=
logging.config=${log.path}log4j2.properties
```

When I start my application I want to find all empty properties and throw Exception in which message there will be information about all missing properties.
Is spring giving that kind of mechanism?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42976820/spring-properties-validation-in-nested-configurationproperties

Answer (score 0):

You can create a bean and bind properties from `application.properties` to bean's fields by adding [`@ConfigurationProperties` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/ConfigurationProperties.html). You can even [use JSR-303 validators like `@NotNull` and `@NotEmpty` for automatic validation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-validation).

If you have too many properties and you don't want to create fields for each of these properties then, probably, you should open and parse `application.properties` file by your own. (But if application uses all these properties, then why not create a bean to validate them in the single place?)

Comment: Its a way to go but sadly I need to explicity write them.
Is there way to maybe iterator on all properties and when there will be one empty property then there will be throwed Exception?
I need do that before for example logger will try to find its log4j2 path or before database will try to connect.
Just before that I want to make list of empty properties, write them in Exception and without explicity write them in class